# guaranteed order of delivery in reactor?

Tags: project-reactor

Does project-reactor guarantee the order in which a publisher delivers things to subscriber(s) by default?  If not, is there a way to guarantee the order in which a publisher delivers things to subscriber(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What guaranteed order would that be?

Short answer is no, there is no *guarantee* (it totally depends on the `Publisher`), but for *practical purposes* it should not be an issue.

most operators will do their best not to mix up the order: the Reactive Streams specification mandates that `onNext` signals MUST happen one before the other, and if reactor-core operator deal with multiple threads they will store each onNext in an atomic `Queue`.

But if a publisher emits A and B from two threads at the same time for example, one thread will atomically "win" and happen before the other, in accordance with the spec. Whether A or B is actually emitted first is nondeterministic at that point.